# I'm thinking of upgrading to a 200 amp service

Tags: electrical

I have a 60 amp main breaker with the following breakers in the panel.

- One 50 amp for range
- One 30 amp for water heater
- One 30 amp breaker for clothes dryer
- Eight 20 amp breakers for appliances
- Five 15 amp for lights.

What size panel do I need?  And does the eletric company have to change the street line, or just the meter?

Comment: and a 50 amp for range

Comment: Is your existing 60A the main breaker? Also, how many square feet is your house?

Comment: it was 60 or 100 amp servise, and the house ia addin a garage that makes it about 1200 sq ft to 1400 sq ft

Comment: Do you have any other appliances that are required to be on a dedicated circuit, are fastened in place, or permanently wired (as opposed to plugged in)?  Also, what are the nameplate wattages for your water heater, range, and clothes dryer?

Comment: Most likely the utility will have to upgrade the service conductors, as well as the meter.  They don't typically install oversized conductors, so an upgrade will require larger wires.

Comment: Why are you considering an upgrade?  Does the main breaker trip? Are you planning to add more electrical devices?

Comment: I would be surprised with that load if the main did not trip every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the USA, the National Electrical Code is used in most areas as the standard for electrical installations. The NEC requires a minimum of 100 amps for a dwelling service.

From there, it only goes higher with the default for most medium to large homes being 200 amps. Without doing a full load calculation most homeowners choose the 200 amp panel that will be almost the same price as a 125 to 175 amp panel.

In most areas, the utility is responsible for the wire to the service drop, or meter socket if it is underground, but the homeowner is responsible for the meter socket on into the house. So, if they decide to upgrade their wiring it is up to the utility. In my area, the utility provides meter sockets for free but the homeowner or contractor must install it.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

If you have had no problems with your electricity, why change the panel?  Changing it costs money, probably a few thousand if an electrician does the work.  I run my house with 70 amp service.  Realize, of course, that the 70 amp is 220 volts, so it is like 140 amp service at 110.  That is enough to run all the lights, computers, dishwasher, washing machine, and AC.  I have thought often of upgrading but have never done it because it works perfectly as is.

Comment: @Kris Didn't I say that? What meaning are you adding?

Comment: @Kris  I thought that is what I said, in simple terms. Did I say it wrong?

Comment: @Kris  I guess I am dense. I do not see the difference between what you wrote and what I wrote. Would you like to point it out?